# Restrict few commands for users in SSH key based authentication?

Tags: ubuntu, openssh, ssh-keys

Currently we are using SSH password authentication, and now we want to move to SSH key based authentication. We have multiple users using the same server. How can we restrict certain users from executing certain commands?

Comment: What commands are you looking to limit? Linux has a huge variety of ways to limit logins and executing things but you need to be more specific in what you need to limit.

Comment: (Too late in the day for me to answer this right now, but just to give you some instant feedback: this is quite possible.  One way is to have an SSH key run a command.  A more flexible way, which serves many purposes, is to allow the SSH key to be less restricted, but to have sudo control what commands are available.  Both methods can be combined.)

Comment: Let's say I want to prevent a user from removing any files. (Restrict user from executing any rm command)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Limited shell or any other tools available to create the limited shell.(Example: [lshell](https://github.com/ghantoos/lshell) Limited Shell )
[You can refer to this link for more details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90998/block-particular-command-in-linux-for-specific-user<br)

**Configuration**
Lshell is configured via an INI file. By default, it holds a whitelist of allowed commands, but it can be easily configured to prohibit the user from using a specific command.
This configuration (default conf `/etc/lshell.conf`) prohibits user `abc` from using `mkdir`:
`[abc]`
 `allowed = 'all' - ['mkdir', 'bash', 'sh', 'csh', 'dash', 'env']`
In order to configure a user account to use lshell by default, you must:
`chsh -s /usr/bin/lshell abc`